# Tab icon not visible in ionic 3

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

Inside ./pages/tabs/tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs>
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="information-
circle"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Settings" tabIcon="cog"></ion-
tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Inside ./pages/tabs/tabs.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import {SettingsPage} from '../settings/settings' ;

@Component({
templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage
{
   tab1Root = HomePage;
   tab2Root = AboutPage;
   tab3Root = SettingsPage;

   constructor() 
   {
   }
}
```

So , I can't understand why I the icons aren't displayed here. Prior to this build , previously it was working. I didn't change anything. Now it isn't working. 
[image: The icons for about,home and settings are missing.]

Comment: you need to cache clean your browser and also re run ionic serve command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Leave tabs.html empty like this.**

```
<ion-content padding></ion-content>
```

**Try this in tabs.ts .**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import {SettingsPage} from '../settings/settings' ;
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
template: `
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-text" [color]="isAndroid ? 'royal' : 'primary'">
    <ion-tab tabIcon="home" tabTitle="Home" [root]="tab1"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="information-circle" tabTitle="About" [root]="tab2"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="cog" tabTitle="Settings" [root]="tab3"></ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
`})

export class TabsPage {
    tab1 = HomePage;
    tab2 = AboutPage;
    tab3 = SettingsPage;
    isAndroid: boolean = false;

    constructor(platform: Platform) {
        this.isAndroid = platform.is('android');
    }    
}
```

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. Additionally people who can not see, and use screen reader get nothing. Please don't do this...

Comment: Will take care from next time :-)

Answer (score 0):

add that to : > scss

```
  .tabbar{opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: Hi! Please add some explanation to your answer. Right now, it is currently being marked as low quality by review due to length and content and is at risk of being deleted by the system. Thanks!